# "Your test errored. Test did not see a new command for 90 seconds. Timing out." Saucelabs

Tags: selenium, behat, saucelabs

I am getting the error when i run test cases on suacelabs. I would like to increase the timeout to `180 seconds`.

I tried this

```
 capabilities: {'platform':'OS X 10.10', 'browser':'chrome', 'version':'45.0', 'idleTimeout':'90'}
```

I am getting this error

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>     Unrecognized option "idleTimeout" under "testwork.mink.sessions.selenium2.selenium2.capabilities"

Answer (score 1):

The `idleTimeout` *is the time that the session will stay alive without receiving a selenium command*. The **default** setting is **90 seconds** and the **max** is **1000 seconds**. To **set** a timeout of **180 seconds**, try the following configuration:

```
caps = {'browserName': "chrome"}
caps['platform'] = "OS X 10.10"
caps['version'] = "45.0"
caps['idleTimeout'] = 180
```

This is a Python example. Examples in other languages can be found [here](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Platform+Configurator#/).

Answer (score 1):

add `driver.quit()`
along with `driver.close()`

If your tests don't include a session ending request, such as a call to `driver.quit()` or `browser.stop()`, they will will keep running forever, consuming all test minutes available in your account. This error is thrown after 90 seconds as a means of preventing this.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but maybe the format of the idleTimeout is wrong?  Try variations on that, like this:

```
capabilities: {'platform':'OS X 10.10', 'browser':'chrome',
   'version':'45.0', 'idle-timeout':90}
```

Comment: Not sure what to suggest then. I would put your test in debug mode and verify the capabilities object is 1. being passed to Saucelabs, 2. contains the value that the SauceLabs docs says it needs.